# Notice: Undefined index: id_field_name in vendor/magento/module-ui/Component/Form.php on line 78

Tags: magento-2.1.3

I am getting this error while editing my form.

This is my code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">zipcode_form.zipcode_form_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">zipcode_form.zipcode_form_data_source</item>
            <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">zipcode_form</item>
        </item>
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">General Information</item>

          <item name="layout" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="type" xsi:type="string">tabs</item>
            <item name="navContainerName" xsi:type="string">left</item>
        </item>

        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="back" xsi:type="string">RB\CheckDelivery\Block\Adminhtml\Zipcode\Edit\BackButton</item>
            <item name="delete" xsi:type="string">RB\CheckDelivery\Block\Adminhtml\Zipcode\Edit\DeleteButton</item>
            <item name="reset" xsi:type="string">RB\CheckDelivery\Block\Adminhtml\Zipcode\Edit\ResetButton</item>
            <item name="save" xsi:type="string">RB\CheckDelivery\Block\Adminhtml\Zipcode\Edit\SaveButton</item>
            <item name="save_and_continue" xsi:type="string">RB\CheckDelivery\Block\Adminhtml\Zipcode\Edit\SaveAndContinueButton</item>
        </item>
    </argument>

    <dataSource name="zipcode_form_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">RB\CheckDelivery\Ui\DataProvider\ZipcodeDataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">zipcode_form_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">zipcode_id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="submit_url" xsi:type="url" path="checkdelivery/zipcode/save"/>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>

        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>


    <fieldset name="zipcodes">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">ZIP Code Information</item>
            </item>
        </argument>


        <field name="zipcode_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">zipcodes</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">zipcode_id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>

        <field name="status">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">boolean</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Enable Zipcode</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">checkbox</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">zipcodes</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">status</item>
                    <item name="prefer" xsi:type="string">toggle</item>
                    <item name="valueMap" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="true" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                        <item name="false" xsi:type="number">0</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="default" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>

        <field name="zipcode">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">ZIP/Postal code</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">zipcodes</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">zipcode</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>

         <field name="country_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Magento\Directory\Model\Config\Source\Country</item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Country</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/country</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">zipcodes</item>
                    <!--<item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">country_id</item>-->
                    <item name="imports" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="default" xsi:type="string">${ $.provider }:data.customer.website_id</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>

        <field name="city">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">City</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">zipcodes</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field> 

<!--         <field name="region">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">address</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>-->

<!--        <field name="region_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">address</item>
                    <item name="customEntry" xsi:type="string">region</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="filterBy" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="target" xsi:type="string">${ $.provider }:${ $.parentScope }.country_id</item>
                        <item name="field" xsi:type="string">country_id</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>-->

    </fieldset>
</form>
```

**ZipcodeDataProvider** :-

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace RB\CheckDelivery\Ui\DataProvider;

use RB\CheckDelivery\Model\ResourceModel\Zipcode\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface;
/**
 * Class ProductDataProvider
 */
class ZipcodeDataProvider extends \Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AbstractDataProvider
{

    /**
     * @var DataPersistorInterface
     */
    private $dataPersistor;

    /**
     * Product collection
     *
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection
     */
    protected $collection;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AddFieldToCollectionInterface[]
     */
    protected $addFieldStrategies;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AddFilterToCollectionInterface[]
     */
    protected $addFilterStrategies;

        /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $loadedData;

    /**
     * Construct
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @param string $primaryFieldName
     * @param string $requestFieldName
     * @param CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
     * @param DataPersistorInterface $dataPersistor
     * @param \Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AddFieldToCollectionInterface[] $addFieldStrategies
     * @param \Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AddFilterToCollectionInterface[] $addFilterStrategies
     * @param array $meta
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        $name,
        $primaryFieldName,
        $requestFieldName,
        CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        DataPersistorInterface $dataPersistor,
        array $addFieldStrategies = [],
        array $addFilterStrategies = [],
        array $meta = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($name, $primaryFieldName, $requestFieldName, $meta, $data);
        $this->collection = $collectionFactory->create();
        $this->addFieldStrategies = $addFieldStrategies;
        $this->addFilterStrategies = $addFilterStrategies;
        $this->dataPersistor = $dataPersistor;
    }

    /**
     * Get data
     *
     * @return array
     */
//    public function getData()
//    {
//        if (!$this->getCollection()->isLoaded()) {
//            $this->getCollection()->load();
//        }
//        $items = $this->getCollection()->toArray();
////        echo '<pre>';
////        print_r(array_values($items));
////        die;
//
////        return $items;
//        return [
//            'totalRecords' => $this->getCollection()->getSize(),
//            'items' => array_values($items),
//        ];
//    }

//     

    /**
     * Add field to select
     *
     * @param string|array $field
     * @param string|null $alias
     * @return void
     */
    public function addField($field, $alias = null)
    {
        if (isset($this->addFieldStrategies[$field])) {
            $this->addFieldStrategies[$field]->addField($this->getCollection(), $field, $alias);
        } else {
            parent::addField($field, $alias);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: add the content of the data provider class `RB\CheckDelivery\Ui\DataProvider\ZipcodeDataProvider`

Comment: @Marius : I have added the code for RB\CheckDelivery\Ui\DataProvider\ZipcodeDataProvider

Comment: @Marius : I guess there is no way to build country, region functionality using UI components, so I have moved to block concept after all they are easy to understand and manage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer a long ago but I guess forgot to share it so I'am updating it considering it might help someone.

So below is the solution :

All you have to do is add given code in your model collection file.

```
protected $_idFieldName = 'block_id'; // Set primary key of your table here..
```

For reference please check this file in core modules : **/var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-cms/Model/ResourceModel/Block/Collection.php**

Comment: Thanks for the update :) it will definitely help future readers !

Answer (score 4):

Inside on your module

yourmodule/Model/Grid/DataProvider.php

You have to place this below getData() function

```
public function getData()
{
    if (isset($this->loadedData)) {
        return $this->loadedData;
    }
    $items = $this->collection->getItems();
    foreach ($items as $model) {
        $this->loadedData[$model->getId()] = $model->getData();
    }
    $data = $this->dataPersistor->get('your_module_variable');

    if (!empty($data)) {
        $model = $this->collection->getNewEmptyItem();
        $model->setData($data);
        $this->loadedData[$model->getId()] = $model->getData();
        $this->dataPersistor->clear('your_module_variable');
    }

    return $this->loadedData;
}
```